# Is binary search tree reconstructed during recursive insertion?

Tags: java, recursion, insert, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

In the regular recursive code for bst, the left and right elements for the tree are set in every recursive call (In t.left= and t.right=).
Isn't this constructing the tree again?

Wouldn't it be better to store a reference to previous node and then add the new node to left or right depending upon the value or am I missing something here? Thanks!

```
      public Elem insert (Elem t, int toInsert)
      {
        if (t == null)
          return new Elem(toInsert,null,null);
        else {
          if (toInsert < t.value)
             t.left  = insert(t.left, toInsert);
          else
             t.right = insert(t.right,toInsert);
          return t;
        }
  }
```

To insert one new element, the code assigns each and every element or sub trees as left and right. My question is that isn't this an overhead? To insert in a linked list, we simply navigate to the last node and perform linkages there. Here, we perform linkages for the whole tree on each insertion. Is there any alternative to avoid this?

Comment: But isn't it assigning left and right references starting from root till the end again for just one insertion?

Comment: Its traversing the tree and not reconstructing

Comment: Could you explain what "conditioning" is? And some details on what actually happens on t.left= and t.right=

Comment: The only time a node is constructed is when the recursion meets its base case. All the other assignments are no ops.

Comment: @Stacky I'd suggest checking out my answer because I believe it addresses your confusion on what recursion actually is.

Comment: Thanks. Added a comment to your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not reconstructing the tree, rather, the method traverses through the tree with recursive calls to get to a leaf (a null spot) within the tree so that the new element can be added there. For example, consider this BST,

```
    6
   / \
  4   8
```

And let's say you called `insert(element 6, 5)` (`*` signifies where we are while traversing through three).

```
   *6
   / \
  4   8
```

The method would skip through the first if-statement, and proceed to check the value of 5 in relation to the current element in the method paramter. 5 is less than 6, so the following line is performed, `t.left  = insert(t.left, toInsert)` (think of this as  elem6.left = insert(element 4, 5)).

```
    6
   / \
 *4   8
```

Now we're on the second method call of `insert`, this time `insert(element 4, 5)`. The first if-statement is skipped once again and 4 is compared to 5. 5 is greater than 4, so the following line is performed, `t.right = insert(t.right,toInsert)` (think of this as elem4.right = insert(null, 5)).

```
    6
   / \
  4   8
   \
    *
```

Now we're on the third method call of 'insert', this time `insert(null, 5)` is called so the first if-statement is actually executed and a new object of type `Elem` is returned. Aka this line is performed, `return new Elem(toInsert,null,null)` (think of this as return new Elem(5, null, null)).

```
    6
   / \
  4   8
   \
    *
```

At this point the call stack begins to decrease after it has grown to three calls. Back to this line, `t.right = insert(t.right,toInsert)` but instead of `insert(t.right, toInsert)`, it's now `new Elem(5, null, null)`. So element 5 has been assigned to the right side of element 4. Then, the rest of the method is executed, ending with `return t`. `t` in this case is the `Elem` passed through the method, element 4.

```
    6
   / \
 *4   8
   \
    5
```

Back to this line (going down the call stack), `t.left  = insert(t.left, toInsert)` but instead of `insert(t.left, toInsert)`, it's now element 4. So the left of element 6 has been assigned to element 4. Then, the rest of the method is executed, ending with `return t`. `t` in this case is the `Elem` passed through the method, element 6. And then the inserting of element 5 has concluded.

```
   *6
   / \
  4   8
   \
    5
```

Comment: Thanks. Suppose we refer to your last paragraph. t.left =4. To insert one new element, the code assigns each and every element or sub trees as left and right. My question is that isn't this an overhead? To insert in a linked list, we simply navigate to the last node and perform linkages there. Here, we perform linkages for the whole tree on each insertion. Is there any alternative to avoid this?

Comment: `5` should be `right` element of `4` rather than `left` element in tree.

Comment: @ashishdwivedi ty sir, I just fixed that.

Comment: @Stacky, that is correct in regard to what's happening. and this is not the only way to insert into a BST, for you can also use a while loop to achieve the same effect. Is there an overhead? Technically yes, but in this case it's minimal. The overhead only gets expensive when there are many recursive calls done. As you will learn though, for certain purposes, it is required to use recursion to traverse through a binary tree.